# Problems setting up the OTA Community Edition workspace

Tags: docker, minikube, ota

Im having trouble setting up my advancedtelematic/ota-community-edition workspace found at https://github.com/advancedtelematic/ota-community-edition

I have installed all the applications listed(mostly via chocolatey). When running the make start, with the docker configuration on my windows machine, I land up with the following error:

```
Can't open /proc/1204/fd/63 for reading, No such file or directory
20036:error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process:../openssl-1.1.1k/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('/proc/1204/fd/63','r')
20036:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../openssl-1.1.1k/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76:
make: *** [Makefile:34: start_start-all] Error 1
```

I wrote some logs and its happening when making use of  openssl req keys inside the new_server() method.

The full log of for the process is below

```
make start
* The control plane node must be running for this command
  To start a cluster, run: "minikube start"
* minikube v1.24.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.19042 Build 19042
* Kubernetes 1.22.3 is now available. If you would like to upgrade, specify: --kubernetes-version=v1.22.3
* Using the docker driver based on existing profile
* Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
* Pulling base image ...
* Restarting existing docker container for "minikube" ...
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.18.3 on Docker 20.10.8 ...
* Verifying Kubernetes components...
  - Using image kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.3.1
  - Using image kubernetesui/metrics-scraper:v1.0.7
  - Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
* Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, dashboard, default-storageclass

! C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\kubectl.exe is version 1.21.2, which may have incompatibilites with Kubernetes 1.18.3.
  - Want kubectl v1.18.3? Try 'minikube kubectl -- get pods -A'
* Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
WARNING: version difference between client (1.21) and server (1.18) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1
serviceaccount/weave-net configured
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/weave-net configured
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/weave-net configured
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/weave-net configured
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/weave-net configured
daemonset.apps/weave-net configured
read EC key
writing EC key
read EC key
writing EC key
sending request to cert
Can't open /proc/1204/fd/63 for reading, No such file or directory
20036:error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process:../openssl-1.1.1k/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('/proc/1204/fd/63','r')
20036:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../openssl-1.1.1k/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76:
make: *** [Makefile:34: start_start-all] Error 1
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the new repo https://github.com/uptane/ota-community-edition  is the new one.

The prolem is that you are using Windows instead of Linux, Use Ubuntu 20.04 for example.

From messing around with this ota-community-edition solution. I think that it's just broken all around. Missing APIs, Unknown APIs, Very bad usage instructions.

At some point the original creators of the repo got bought by another comapny, and from what it looks ota-community-edition is just not usable and not mantained.

Update:
For device you should use: https://github.com/advancedtelematic/aktualizr/tree/5336fd20bb59ebfcc4ef0285128dece7e0412867   newer versions are broken. It might be fixable (By you by messing around somewhere), After you'll use the Download API call newer versions will try to execute event:8443 call which will fail.
(https://github.com/advancedtelematic/libaktualizr-demo-app)

https://github.com/simao/ota-cli  this one for server interaction.
you'll have to edit: .../ota-community-edition/templates/services .toml files of campaigner, director and registry to export the host... you can see app.tmpl.yaml for an example of how to do it.

Comment: Thank you, we did end up using that repo and things went a lot smoother. Really difficult to get started on this subject with the state of some of the repos and copied branches etc

Comment: no problem, It is one of the hardest ones to work with, check my answer again I've just add for you more information.